# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: when Index and Size are the same

Tags: java, arrays

I'm currently trying to solve this coding question. I have the code to compile properly for some use cases......though, I'm getting a weird error whenever the index and the size are the same value. (Ex: Index: 4, and Size: 4 || Index: 7, Size: 7). The input for this function consists of an argument known as area, which represents two-dimensional grid of integers. (Ex: area = [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 9, 1]). Could anyone possibly see what's causing this issue for those types of use cases?

```
 public static int minimumDistance(List<List<Integer>> area) {
        if(area == null)
            return -1;
        if(area.size() <= 0 || area.get(0).size()<=0)
            return -1;
        Queue<int[]> p = new LinkedList<>();
        boolean[][] visited = new boolean[area.size()][area.get(0).size()];
        int[][] directions = new int[][]{{0,1}, {0,-1}, {1,0}, {-1, 0}};
        p.add(new int[]{0,0});
        int result = 0;
        while(p.size() > 0){
            int size = p.size();
            
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                int[] node = p.poll();
                int x = node[0];
                int y = node[1];
                visited[x][y] = true;
                if(area.get(x).get(y) == 9)
                    return result;
                    
                for(int[] dirt: directions){
                    int nx = x + dirt[0];
                    int ny = y + dirt[1];
                    
                    if(nx < 0 || nx >= area.size() || ny < 0 || ny > area.get(nx).size() || area.get(nx).get(ny) == 0 ||
                       visited[nx][ny] == true)
                       continue;
                    p.offer(new int[]{nx,ny}); 
                }
            }
            result++;
        }
        return -1;
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 7, Size: 7
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
    at Result.minimumDistance(Solution.java:48)
    at Solution.main(Solution.java:82)
Your Output (stdout)
```

Comment: Index is zero-based. So index 7 is looking for the 8th element, which won't exist in a collection of 7 elements. Right?

Comment: Looks like it, is there any way to get around or make an adjustment to that?

Comment: Make sure that your index always remains below the size.

Comment: Where would it be best to put that to ensure that index remains below the size?

Comment: The Java Language Specification, section [10.4. Array Access](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.4) says: *"All array accesses are checked at run time; an attempt to use an index that is less than zero or greater than **or equal to the length of the array causes an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`** to be thrown."* --- Similarly, the javadoc of `List.get(i)` says: *"Throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the index is out of range (index < 0 || **index >= size()**)"* --- In both cases, it is well-documented that the index must be less than the size.

Comment: Change `ny > area.get(nx).size()` to `ny >= area.get(nx).size()`